# Enable versioning for all the lists under a site through site definition

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, versioning, site-definition, onet

I want to enable versioning for all the lists under a site through site definition xml.

> **Note**: Would not prefer powerhshell script.

Comment: I am not sure through site definition. But you can surely modify list definitions and enable version in that. It will also help. But you can to modify all list definitions for this.